# JSColor update background colours after loading values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscolor

The background color of JScolor picker doesn't update when the value is loaded.

I searched on google for the solution, but they are all in JQuery, like these:

http://activelab.io/troubleshooting/jscolor-update-background-colours-after-loading-values

and

```
$('.jscolorinput').each(function()
{
    $(this)[0].color.fromString($(this).val());
});
```

what's the JavaScript way to do it?

---

I got it now.
The background color of the color picker can be assessed by document.getElementById('someID').jscolor.valueElement.style.backgroundColor

But there is a problem, the above style has to be in the form of "rbg(aa,bb,cc)", while the JScolor value is in HEX

Therefore you need to first write a function to convert HEX code to the right form:

```
function HEX_rgb (hex){
    var a = 'rgb(' + parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16) + ", " + parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16) + ", " + parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16) + ')';
    return a;
}
```

Then change the background color:

```
document.getElementById('someID').jscolor.valueElement.style.backgroundColor = HEX_rgb(//The HEX code);
```

By the way, the background color will actually update if you click on and off the input box without changing the value inside.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but it work well for me.

```js
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('jscolor');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
  inputs[i].setAttribute('value', 'ffffff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
<input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `getElementsByClassName` and iterate each one in a loop

```js
function update(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    var color = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
    
    
    for(var i=0, len=color.length; i<len; i++)
    {
        color[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
    }
}
```

```css
.color{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
<input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="ffffff">
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
```